# Как изменить количество элементов(размер) массива строк char работа с которым ведётся через указатель в Borland C++ Builder 6?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, char, borland-c++

Есть указатель на некоторый массив, например такой.

```
*test[2] = {{"Odin"},{"Dva"}};
```

Требуется изменить количество элементов в этом массиве, например до 3-х, как это сделать? В Интернет нашёл, что есть функция realloc, как именно ей воспользоваться для данного случая пока что не понял.

Вот вариант который не компилируется:

```
test = (char *)(realloc(test,12));//возможно нужно указывать не 12, а 3, указал 12 поскольку каждый элемент в sizeof(test) добавляет 4 к длине.
```

Как переписать этот вариант чтобы код скомпилировался?

Так же в интернете нашёл предлагаемую функцию для изменение массива с созданием нового указателя на массив и дальнейшим копированием в него элементов. Если существует вариант без создания новой переменной пожалуйста напишите какой?

Comment: `*test[2] = {{"Odin"},{"Dva"}};` запись невалидная. Количество элементов в массиве не изменяется после создания объекта. Используйте `std::vector`.

Comment: Указанная строчка компилируется, после чего можно обращаться к элементам и изменять их, а sizeof возвращает значение длины. Рассматриваю вариант с указателем на массив строк char, то есть без vector и array.

Comment: Возможно нужно объявлять такой массив так что после знака равно использовать malloc с указанием размера. Пока не понял как именно использовать такой вариант, то есть что то на подобии char **test = (char **)malloc(12); такая сточка компилируется при этом sizoof(test) возвращает 4 а не 12.

Comment: *"Указанная строчка компилируется, после чего можно обращаться к элементам и изменять их, а sizeof возвращает значение длины."* - [она не компилируется](https://godbolt.org/z/3r9444xbE)

Comment: Она компилируется - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgJdJayq3Pg

Comment: Это просто рука лицо...

Comment: @ottofors, так компилируется строка `char* test[2]...`

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Вам необходимо использовать std::vector или любой другой контейнер который подходит для вашей задачи. Если вам нужно что-то экзотическое, что ещё не реализовано где-то - можете написать свой контейнер с использованием new[] и delete[].

Массив такого типа: `T array[n]` будет храниться на стеке, и использовать realloc() на нём нельзя, тк функция работает только с памятью в куче.

Comment: То есть не существует возможности выделить память для массива строк char как то например через malloc таким образом чтобы можно было бы определить его длину через siozof(или какой то другой стандартной функцией)?

Comment: sizeof() работает во время компиляции. Простая подстановка размера какого-то типа. Вообще - нельзя. Но есть, конечно, способ один - _msize() функция. Не знаю точно, почему её так не любят, потому и рекомендовать её не буду. Уверен в вашем случае можно найти намного более хороший способ решения задачи. Почему-бы не использовать std::vector? Кстати, есть рекомендация избавляться от malloc()/free() функций, тк в них нет исключений как в тех же new[]/delete[]. Наверное, это и есть причина ненавести к _msize(), тк это тоже C функция. @ottofors

Comment: Вопрос по поводу vectora мне уже задавали в предыдущих моих вопросах - причина в том числе в том что у меня другой основной язык, при этом давно были планы на c++. И вот наконец то начал двигаться в этом направлении. Считаю что не плохо для понимания разобраться как именно этот язык работает с памятью и в частности указателями, использовать vector я всегда успею. То есть для начала разберусь с указателями на строки char и их массивы. _msize встречалась в примерах кода, пока не понял как работает.